# How to zoom layout with dynamic views in android?

Tags: android, zooming, pinchzoom

I can able to zoom my layout. My java code is here http://pastie.org/9327072 . My xml code is here http://pastie.org/9327076. I am taking zoom class from here   [link](https://github.com/Polidea/android-zoom-view/blob/master/src/pl/polidea/view/ZoomView.java)
I created layout via xml and i created an image view via code. I placed my image view in some pixels. Now  My issue is my layout is zooming perfectly. But my dynamic image doesn't zoom simultaneously. Otherwise it will be stay in same place. Because i need to zoom layout with dynamic view. How can i resolve this? Can any body tell me? Thanks in advance.